# Is there a way for me to combine these 3 methods into just 1?

Tags: objective-c, encapsulation

Basically, I have 3 delegate methods that have almost the exact same code except for 1 line in each and the parameters. I realize that I can encapsulate a lot of the code to make 3 or 4 lines of code in each method, but I'm wondering if there's a way to create just 1 method.

Also, the methods being called on `tempData` have the same method name as the delegate methods below, but they are actually different methods.

```
- (void)addElement:(NSString *)currentElement FromKeyboard:(NSString *)name {

    UIView *tempView; 
    NSMutableArray *tempViewList;
    EquationData *tempData;    


    if ([name isEqualToString:@"leftEqCellKeyboard"]) {
        tempData = leftData;
        tempViewList = leftEqViewList;
        tempView = equationCell.leftView;
    }

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"rightEqCellKeyboard"]) {
        tempData = rightData;
        tempViewList = rightEqViewList;
        tempView = equationCell.rightView;
    }

    [tempData addElement:currentElement]; // different

    if ([tempViewList count] != 0) 
        [self clearViewsStoredIn:tempViewList];
    [self setUpView:tempView fromArray:tempData.equation toArray:tempViewList];
}

- (void)changeState:(NSString *)stateName FromKeyboard:(NSString *)name {

   UIView *tempView; 
    NSMutableArray *tempViewList;
    EquationData *tempData;    

 if ([name isEqualToString:@"leftEqCellKeyboard"]) {
        tempData = leftData;
        tempViewList = leftEqViewList;
        tempView = equationCell.leftView;
    }

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"rightEqCellKeyboard"]) {
        tempData = rightData;
        tempViewList = rightEqViewList;
        tempView = equationCell.rightView;
    }

    [tempData changeState:stateName]; // different

    if ([tempViewList count] != 0) 
        [self clearViewsStoredIn:tempViewList];

       [self setUpView:tempView fromArray:tempData.equation toArray:tempViewList];

}

- (void)changeCharge:(NSString *)chargeIncrease FromKeyboard:(NSString *)name {

    UIView *tempView;
    NSMutableArray *tempViewList;
    EquationData *tempData;   

if ([name isEqualToString:@"leftEqCellKeyboard"]) {
        tempData = leftData;
        tempViewList = leftEqViewList;
        tempView = equationCell.leftView;
    }

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"rightEqCellKeyboard"]) {
        tempData = rightData;
        tempViewList = rightEqViewList;
        tempView = equationCell.rightView;
    }  
    [tempData changeCharge:chargeIncrease]; // different

    if ([tempViewList count] != 0) 
        [self clearViewsStoredIn:tempViewList];

    [self setUpView:tempView fromArray:tempData.equation toArray:tempViewList];


}
```

Comment: I don't know how to code in Objective C, but could you use a switch statement with an int to compare which action to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Perhaps you should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

The "different" part is always of the form `[tempData doSomethingOn:aString];`, so you can parametrize with the **selector** "doSomethingOn:":

```
-(void)doSomethingOnString:(NSString*)parameter 
              withSelector:(SEL)selector
              fromKeyboard:(NSString*)name 
{
    // The common parts before

    [tempData performSelector:selector withObject:parameter];

    // The common parts after
}

-(void)addElement:(NSString *)currentElement FromKeyboard:(NSString *)name {
    [self doSomethingOnString:currentElement
                 withSelector:@selector(addElement:)
                 fromKeyboard:name];
}

// etc.
```

See also:

- [`-performSelector:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3a)
- [The "Selector" concept in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html)

Comment: Instead of calling the `addElement:` method and then calling the `doSomething:` method, I directly call `[delegate doSomething:button.titleLabel.text withSelector:@selector(addElement:) fromKeyboard:self.name]`, but I'm getting an unrecognized selector error

Comment: Never mind, I realized that the `@selector` was not needed. Ignore above comment